# Express renders a wrong page

Tags: express

I have this code in my userController.js:

```
exports.deleteUser = async (request, response) => {
    const user_id = request.params.id;

    try {
        // Delete the user
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mysqlConnection.query('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=?', [user_id], (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('User deleted');
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        });

        // Select all users after the deletion
        const usersData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            mysqlConnection.query('SELECT * FROM users', (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);
                }
            });
        });
        //render admin_users
        response.render('admin_users', { data: usersData });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(500).send('Error deleting user');
    }
};
```

It's called from admin_users.ejs:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Administration</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = '/Styles/styles.css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">        
            <div id="top-menu">
                <%- include ("./partials/menu") %></div>
            <div id="header">Header</div>
            <div id="status_bar">Status_bar</div>
            <div id="content">
                <div id="admin_menu">
                    <a href="/admin/admin_articles">Articles Admin.</a>
                    <a href="/admin/admin_comments">Comments Admin.</a>
                    <a href="/admin/admin_users">Users Admin.</a>
                </div>
                <div id="category_menu">
                    <a href="/users/create_user">Create User</a>                    
                </div>
                
                <div id ="Users_list">List Of Users:
                    <table>
                        <tr><td>User</td><td>User Password</td><td>User Create Date</td></tr>
                        <% data.forEach(entry => { %>
                        <tr>
                            <td><%= entry.user_name %></td>
                            <td><%= entry.user_password %></td>
                            <td><%= entry.user_create_date %></td> 
                            <td><a href="../users/edit_user/<%= entry.user_id %>">EDIT</a>
                                <a href="../users/delete_user/<%= entry.user_id %>">DELETE</a></td>                            
                        </tr>
                        <% }) %>
                    </table>
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <div id="footer"><%- include ("./partials/footer") %></div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The record in db is removed, and the page is rendered with updated list, but I end up at

`http://localhost:3000/users/delete_user/56` instead of `http://localhost:3000/admin/admin_users` where it should. And it breaks my routing.

I am really new to this whole programming thing, so I really tried to figure out what's wrong for quite a some time, but at this moment I am quite sure I just don't understand some basic concept. Can you guys help me here?